# trigger watch function in Vue 3 composition Api

Tags: javascript, watch, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have set this reactive value inside the setup

`const refValue = ref('foo');`

and set a `watch` function to it

```
     watch(refValue, function() {
       console.log("activaded")
    
    });
```

the `watch` function gets not activated if I manually change the value,

it gets only activated if a add a function which changes the value

```
 const changeValue = function changedValue() {
      console.log("fired");

      return refValue.value = 12;
    }
```

why does watch only gets triggered when using a function to change the value,

I thought  that  `const refValue = ref('foo');` is reactive so `watch` should detect all changes

```
import { ref,watch } from 'vue';

export default {
  setup() {
    
    const refValue = ref('foo');
 

     watch(refValue, function() {
       console.log("activaded")
    
    });

    const changeValue = function changedValue() {
      console.log("fired");

      return refValue.value = 12;
    }



    return {
      refProp: refValue,
      changeFuncton: changeValue
     
    };
  },

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out `immediate` option and use a function as first parameter that returns the observed property :

```
   watch(()=>refValue, function() {
       console.log("activaded")
    
    },{immediate:true});
```

Answer (score 0):

refValue type is an object.

vue watchs for refValue object **reference** change, not property change